# Unable to identify exact xpath if there are more than 1 listed elements via Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, identify

I have a html code as

```
..

/div[2]/div[1]/ol/**li[1]**/header/div[2]
   ...

/div[2]/div[1]/ol/**li[2]**/header/div[2]
   ...
```

means two orderly listed items

So if i try searching for `/div[2]/div[1]/ol/**li**/header/div[2]`, my selenium code says exists, but actually it doesn't. I think my selenium code is pointing out the headers in both of the listed items. How to fail the code if `/div[2]/div[1]/ol/**li**/header/div[2]` this doesn't exist.

Comment: Why you say the list doesnt exist?. If its in html code it does exist. You mean is not visible?

Comment: list exists but there are 2 list items. xPath of the list is not correct. If u search for /div[2]/div[1]/ol/li/header/div[2] it should fail as only /div[2]/div[1]/ol/li[1]/header/div[2] or /div[2]/div[1]/ol/li[2]/header/div[2] exists

Comment: Actually it **does exist**. In XPath, `.../li/...` without index means all `li` (both `../li[1]/..` & `../li[2]/..` in your example)

Comment: But how to make my selenium fail if it searches for /li/ when it has indexes in it like /li[1]/ or /li[2]/. Workaround that I have done here is if /li[2]/ exists means list of items are present.

Comment: You need to post example of the page you are trying to target.